# How to make some words disappear and appear based on more conditions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok, so I have javascript and CSS that makes words appear and then disappear permanently based on whether or not the mouse is hovering over them. Some words (`exceptions`) remain visible the entire time. I'm trying to make it so there are some words that are invisible at first, but only after being hovered over, appear. Any thoughts? I've added a `moreExceptions` variable, that I hope to manipulate in this way. Other than that, I'm stumped. Sorry, I'm really not a coder.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var exceptions = ["Bulls", "rhymes,", "spin", "blinding", "pinched", "oxygen", "tendrils", "exact", "agreement", "combination", "swallow", "smiles",
                  "mirror", "treehouse", "project", "dwindling", "laughing", "fall", "stupor", "breaking", "skin", "untimely"];

var moreExceptions = ["you", "that"];

$("p").each(function() {           //for all paragraphs

    var txt = $(this).text()       //get text, split it up, add spans where necessary, put it back together
        .split(" ")
        .map(function(x) {
        return exceptions.includes(x.toLowerCase()) ? x : "<span class='hover'>" + x + "</span>"}).join(" ");
    $(this).html(txt);             //set the text to our newly manipulated text

}).on("mouseover", ".hover", function() {

    $(this).addClass("hovering");  //set opacity to 100%

}).on("mouseout", ".hovering", function() {
    $(this).attr("class", "");     //set opacity to 0%, remove "hover" events

});
});
```

CSS:

```
* {
    background-color: black
}

h1 {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0.5;
}


img {

    width: 10%;
    height: 10%
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.hover {
    opacity: 0;
}

.hovering {
    opacity: 1;
}

span {
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
    opacity: 0;
}

p {
    cursor: default;
    line-height: 200%;
    border-bottom: solid;
    border-color: rgb(50, 50, 50);
    color: white;
    font-size: 50px;
}

.instructions {
    color: white;
}


@-webkit-keyframes p {
  0% { border-color: rgb(50, 50, 50); }
  100% { border-color: rgb(20, 20, 20); }
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "NarrativeTheory.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src="NarrativeTheory.js"></script>
<div class= "instructions">
Place your cursor directly below the arrow, and follow the lines right-to-left. Fullscreen your browser for best effect.
</div>
</head>

<body>
<img src="arrow.png"> 

<br>

<div class = story>

<p>
        "Do you see it?" The Grandmaster calls out, "The Second </p> <p> Star?" James did not see the Second Star, not even through the </p> <p> telescope,
    but then again he was never very good at spotting </p> <p> constellations. He remembers how his neighbor used to point </p> <p> them out to him
    during neighborhood barbeques. Bulls and </p> <p> lions so stolidly sitting in the sky. Those beasts you often hear </p> <p> about in the Bible.
    When you actually saw them-at the zoo </p> <p> or something-they looked quite pitiable and stupid. This is not </p> <p> like that; this is science.
    No mythologies, characters or </p> <p> rhymes; only astronomy and physics.
   "We see it!" Calls out </p> <p> a young woman, about his own age. Her voice is smooth and </p> <p> bursting with piety. She and some other folks are
   dancing </p> <p> around, giddy at the coming transformation. She's not </p> <p> extraordinarily pretty-none of them are really-but the glow of </p> <p> their
   joy, the pure bliss that shines off of them in every </p> <p> direction makes fine nymphs out of them. The childish spirits </p> <p>  spin around and
   giggle, jumping like stray flames from the </p> <p>  bonfire that had burned earlier. He admires them deeply. </p> <p> He is a very large man, and
   although he has been working</p> <p> toward letting his spirit fly free, he is not yet able to dance </p> <p> with such blaze. 
"Come here children! Settle down!" The </p> <p> Grandmaster shouts, wiping his brow. "Do you know why we </p> <p> live out here?" he pauses, seemingly
inhabited by some </p> <p> wayward astral-flower, and sniffs. "Well, alright I'll tell you. </p> <p> You see, the city is blinding; wayward light leaks 
from every </p> <p> window." His voice softens, and he looks at us as a father </p> <p> would, "And so here we are, come to a place of peace; where </p> <p> the 
infinite pinched points of the universe, stream  along in a </p> <p> dance of profound revelry. Where power doesn't exist except </p> <p> for the collective 
power. Come to me. Let's hold each other </p> <p> now." 
Two women rush to either side of the Grandmaster </p> <p> eagerly, as if trying to catch a butterfly. The whole group grabs </p> <p> ahold of each other, 
however they can. Even though there are </p> <p> at least eleven people between him and the Grandmaster, </p> <p>  James can still feel the tendrils of energy 
reach him through </p> <p> the others. It feels warm and exact. His body reverberates with </p> <p> the excitation. He feels himself drawing closer to the </p> <p> 
frequency of their leader-the Natural Frequency. 
"The light is </p> <p> coming to carry us children! We shall soon ascend and </p> <p> transcend. As both particle and wave we will rise from this </p> <p> earth. 
As the ultimate purveyor of knowledge-we shall </p> <p> become light itself, if only we prepare our bodies to reach the </p> <p> Natural Frequency." His face
and voice darken at once, "While </p> <p> the unattuned become the less than dark, the nothing they have </p> <p> always secretly known themselves to be."
Moans of agreement </p> <p> and ecstasy echo between the Children and the Grandmaster.</p> <p> The energy compounds between them. The Resonance is </p> <p> beginning. 
The Second Star and the First Star have grown </p> <p> closer. They are almost exactly seven light-years apart now. </p> <p> The Grandmaster tells them that this
is the perfect distance </p> <p> away. Tonight the combination of their light will produce the </p> <p> Perfect Wave, a wave of light that contains frequencies 
in </p> <p> perfect alignment with the frequency of both an electron and</p> <p> a proton-the Natural Frequency. The rest of the world will </p> <p> fade, but the
Children will join the light due to their perfect </p> <p> attunement. 
"The world is so dark," the Grandmaster begins </p> <p> again, sobbing, "It's so dark. It's just not fair." The rest of the </p> <p> group begins to cry as
well. Their passionate moans have </p> <p> turned to despairing wails. James too sheds a few tears. He </p> <p> couldn't convince them. They wouldn't come with 
him. "We </p> <p> tried to free them Children. We really did try our best. But it's </p> <p> time to go. Let's swallow them down and begin the </p> <p> Attunement." 
James looks at the Attunement Agent in his </p> <p> hand, designed by the Grandmaster himself to allow the </p> <p> frequencies of his body to merge with the 
Natural Frequency. </p> <p> He puts the pill in his mouth, and takes a swig from the </p> <p> water bottle that someone has evidently handed him. As he </p> <p> throws 
his head back to swallow the pill, he sees the stars, </p> <p> mutely dinging in the sky. He feels very, very good now.</p>
<p>**************************************************************************************************************************************************************</p>
<p> James wakes up. There is still a world. He is not light, but he </p> <p>  is still something. He misses the feeling he felt before. Again </p> <p> hungry for
the flesh of imagined sweetings, he rises to his feet. </p> <p>  They feel very heavy. He takes off his shoes and ties the </p> <p> shoelaces together and they dangle 
from his fingertips, like </p> <p> dice on a rear view mirror, as he wanders through a forest </p> <p>  unknown to him. He moves towards what little bonfire smoke </p> <p> remained
from the campsite.  The sun is up, but just barely. As </p> <p>  he walks he sees the other children, some of them huddled </p> <p>  together, still sleeping, with smiles on 
their faces. Others look </p> <p>  a lot like him, wandering around aimlessly. He is too afraid to </p> <p> speak to them. The energy is gone. They are all still here. 
We </p> <p>  are all still here. Very still.
Where is the grandmaster? Has he </p> <p>  ascended? If he had ascended, why are the children still here? </p> <p>  Why is everything still here? He comes out of the
woods, into </p> <p>  the clearing where they have built their houses. There is no </p> <p> music playing, as there so often was. It is beginning to rain. </p> <p>  Good for the
crops. He eyes the grandmaster's treehouse. He has </p> <p> never been there. Grandmaster always told them that they </p> <p> should not visit his lodging unless it was 
an absolute </p> <p> emergency. And even then, if Daydream was available, they </p> <p> were supposed to tell her and she was to summon him. But if </p><p> there ever was an 
emergency, this was it. Striding towards the </p> <p> abode of the mistaken soothsayer, he tries to project confidence </p> <p> as best as he can, but he is sure it is
not working.
He arrives at </p> <p> the bottom of the rope ladder, and calls up to the grandmaster. </p> <p> "Grandmaster!" He is surprised to hear his own voice; he had </p> <p>not heard
it by itself for so long. It does not sound the way that </p> <p> he remembered it. But there is no response. He yells louder, but </p> <p> still no reply. He looks around
warily, seeing only wayward </p> <p> children still dwindling around the edge of the woods, unsure of </p> <p> how to continue. He drops his shoes and takes a step onto the </p> <p>
ladder. He struggles even to balance on the first rung, but </p> <p> pushes up. Swinging back and forth, he forces himself to reach </p> <p> the top. He places his elbows
on the floorboards, and peers </p> <p> through the open door. There the grandmaster sits. His throat </p> <p> laughing blood, Daydream sleeping forever in his arms.
 James </p> <p>  falls. It's about a six foot drop. Nothing terrible, but air seems </p> <p>  to flit away from him with each breath now. He lays on his </p> <p> back. The oxygen
is coming back to him, a tempestuous sylph </p> <p> seeming sometimes to tempt him with an especially full breath</p> <p> before teasing away again. But as he lays, it 
comes back to him. </p> <p> It gets easier and by the end he breathes easily, his own form of </p> <p> meditation. Some time passes, he is not sure how much, before </p> <p> he
rises to his feet. He is not sure whether he is in shock, but the </p> <p> pain of the fall seems to have displaced the horror of what he </p> <p> had seen.
He goes back to his quarters, an old school bus that he </p> <p> shares with about eight other men as living quarters. The </p> <p> steering wheel was still attached,
but the bus did not drive. Idly, </p> <p> he sits and gives the steering wheel a turn or two. One man lays </p> <p> on his mat, blissful and unconscious, like a stuffed 
animal. He </p> <p> must have made his way back in the technicolor stupor. Habit is </p> <p> a powerful hand to hold. Again, James is too afraid to wake </p> <p> him, too afraid
to speak to him. He does not know these people. </p> <p> He only knows the grandmaster, and he has gone. 
James sits </p> <p> incredulous in the seat of the bus. A riddling strand of accordion </p> <p> rain weeps across the window, leaving behind it a trail of </p> <p>
self-fragments before breaking up into nothing. The silence </p> <p> which at first oppressed him, seemed to conjure up a kind of </p> <p> peace within him now. 
There was no silence before. No matter </p> <p> how early you woke up. Always people singing, yelling, </p> <p> chanting their mantras, or perhaps the grandmaster 
would be </p> <p> giving a sermon. He had a booming voice, one that really got </p> <p> under your skin and frisked your spirit. But now, the noise </p> <p> subsided, James
can think again.
He thinks first about how he </p> <p> has no wallet, no ID, no social security number, no cellphone </p> <p> and how there’s no landline. He then thinks about how 
he's not </p> <p> sure how to get home, or if there still is a home. He hasn't talked </p> <p> to his mother or father in years. They probably would not have </p> <p> missed
him anyway. What is there for him, out there? But then, </p> <p> what is here? He peers out the window. It seems that the </p> <p> children have discovered the untimely 
death of the grandmaster. </p> <p> They are tearing anything and everything apart. They are </p> <p> pulling the crops up, biting them and then spitting them onto </p> <p> the
ground. The shepherd has gone, and the sheep have grown </p> <p> rabid in his absence.
James isn't quite sure what to do. So he </p> <p> just holds the steering wheel of the old school bus, and turns it. </p> <p> Round and round, round and round.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/nLz5h2ub/#&togetherjs=jaOGLpUNab

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPD** I like the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43794485/2542172) with CSS by [Joe Higley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5158272/joe-higley)

Look at this.

I added css class `.alwaysVisible`, which is same as `.hovering`

Then in JS use `#[removeClass][1]` onmouseout

P.S. I also made your Exception words #toLowerCase (because some words in there were capitalized)..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

var exceptions = ["bulls", "rhymes,", "spin", "blinding", "pinched", "oxygen", "tendrils", "exact", "agreement", "combination", "swallow", "smiles",
                  "mirror", "treehouse", "project", "dwindling", "laughing", "fall", "stupor", "breaking", "skin", "untimely"];

var moreExceptions = ["you", "that"];

  $("p").each(function() {           //for all paragraphs

      var txt = $(this).text()       //get text, split it up, add spans where necessary, put it back together
          .split(" ")
          .map( function(x) {
          
            var $word = $("<span>").text(x); //create '<span>'+x+'</span>' as jQuery object
            if(exceptions.includes(x.toLowerCase())){
              return $word.addClass("alwaysVisible").prop("outerHTML"); //return object as a string
            }
            
            if(moreExceptions.includes(x.toLowerCase())){
              $word.addClass("hiddenAtFirst"); //special class for words from moreException
            }
            return $word.addClass("hover").prop("outerHTML"); 
            
          }).join(" ");

      $(this).html(txt);             //set the text to our newly manipulated text

  }).on("mouseout", ".hover", function() {
      $(this).removeClass("hover"); // without .hover it will not reappear again 
      
      //if it's from moreException list
      if($(this).hasClass("hiddenAtFirst")){
        $(this).addClass("alwaysVisible");  //make it alwaysVisible
      }
  });
});
```

```css
* {
    background-color: black
}

h1 {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0.5;
}


img {

    width: 10%;
    height: 10%
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.hover {
    opacity: 0;
}

/* VISIBLE */
.alwaysVisible, .hover:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

span {
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
    opacity: 0;
}

p {
    cursor: default;
    line-height: 200%;
    border-bottom: solid;
    border-color: rgb(50, 50, 50);
    color: white;
    font-size: 50px;
}

.instructions {
    color: white;
}


@-webkit-keyframes p {
  0% { border-color: rgb(50, 50, 50); }
  100% { border-color: rgb(20, 20, 20); }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class = story>

<p>
        "Do you see it?" The Grandmaster calls out, "The Second </p> <p> Star?" James did not see the Second Star, not even through the </p> <p> telescope,
    but then again he was never very good at spotting </p> <p> constellations. He remembers how his neighbor used to point </p> <p> them out to him
    during neighborhood barbeques. Bulls and </p> <p> lions so stolidly sitting in the sky. Those beasts you often hear </p> <p> about in the Bible.
    When you actually saw them-at the zoo </p> <p> or something-they looked quite pitiable and stupid. This is not </p> <p> like that; this is science.
    No mythologies, characters or </p> <p> rhymes; only astronomy and physics.
   "We see it!" Calls out </p> <p> a young woman, about his own age. Her voice is smooth and </p> <p> bursting with piety. She and some other folks are
   dancing </p> <p> around, giddy at the coming transformation. She's not </p> <p> extraordinarily pretty-none of them are really-but the glow of </p> <p> their
   joy, the pure bliss that shines off of them in every </p> <p> direction makes fine nymphs out of them. The childish spirits </p> <p>  spin around and
   giggle, jumping like stray flames from the </p> <p>  bonfire that had burned earlier. He admires them deeply. </p> <p> He is a very large man, and
   although he has been working</p> <p> toward letting his spirit fly free, he is not yet able to dance </p> <p> with such blaze. 
"Come here children! Settle down!" The </p> <p> Grandmaster shouts, wiping his brow. "Do you know why we </p> <p> live out here?" he pauses, seemingly
inhabited by some </p> <p> wayward astral-flower, and sniffs. "Well, alright I'll tell you. </p> <p> You see, the city is blinding; wayward light leaks 
from every </p> <p> window." His voice softens, and he looks at us as a father </p> <p> would, "And so here we are, come to a place of peace; where </p> <p> the 
infinite pinched points of the universe, stream  along in a </p> <p> dance of profound revelry. Where power doesn't exist except </p> <p> for the collective 
power. Come to me. Let's hold each other </p> <p> now." 
Two women rush to either side of the Grandmaster </p> <p> eagerly, as if trying to catch a butterfly. The whole group grabs </p> <p> ahold of each other, 
however they can. Even though there are </p> <p> at least eleven people between him and the Grandmaster, </p> <p>  James can still feel the tendrils of energy 
reach him through </p> <p> the others. It feels warm and exact. His body reverberates with </p> <p> the excitation. He feels himself drawing closer to the </p> <p> 
frequency of their leader-the Natural Frequency. 
"The light is </p> <p> coming to carry us children! We shall soon ascend and </p> <p> transcend. As both particle and wave we will rise from this </p> <p> earth. 
As the ultimate purveyor of knowledge-we shall </p> <p> become light itself, if only we prepare our bodies to reach the </p> <p> Natural Frequency." His face
and voice darken at once, "While </p> <p> the unattuned become the less than dark, the nothing they have </p> <p> always secretly known themselves to be."
Moans of agreement </p> <p> and ecstasy echo between the Children and the Grandmaster.</p> <p> The energy compounds between them. The Resonance is </p> <p> beginning. 
The Second Star and the First Star have grown </p> <p> closer. They are almost exactly seven light-years apart now. </p> <p> The Grandmaster tells them that this
is the perfect distance </p> <p> away. Tonight the combination of their light will produce the </p> <p> Perfect Wave, a wave of light that contains frequencies 
in </p> <p> perfect alignment with the frequency of both an electron and</p> <p> a proton-the Natural Frequency. The rest of the world will </p> <p> fade, but the
Children will join the light due to their perfect </p> <p> attunement. 
"The world is so dark," the Grandmaster begins </p> <p> again, sobbing, "It's so dark. It's just not fair." The rest of the </p> <p> group begins to cry as
well. Their passionate moans have </p> <p> turned to despairing wails. James too sheds a few tears. He </p> <p> couldn't convince them. They wouldn't come with 
him. "We </p> <p> tried to free them Children. We really did try our best. But it's </p> <p> time to go. Let's swallow them down and begin the </p> <p> Attunement." 
James looks at the Attunement Agent in his </p> <p> hand, designed by the Grandmaster himself to allow the </p> <p> frequencies of his body to merge with the 
Natural Frequency. </p> <p> He puts the pill in his mouth, and takes a swig from the </p> <p> water bottle that someone has evidently handed him. As he </p> <p> throws 
his head back to swallow the pill, he sees the stars, </p> <p> mutely dinging in the sky. He feels very, very good now.</p>
<p>**************************************************************************************************************************************************************</p>
<p> James wakes up. There is still a world. He is not light, but he </p> <p>  is still something. He misses the feeling he felt before. Again </p> <p> hungry for
the flesh of imagined sweetings, he rises to his feet. </p> <p>  They feel very heavy. He takes off his shoes and ties the </p> <p> shoelaces together and they dangle 
from his fingertips, like </p> <p> dice on a rear view mirror, as he wanders through a forest </p> <p>  unknown to him. He moves towards what little bonfire smoke </p> <p> remained
from the campsite.  The sun is up, but just barely. As </p> <p>  he walks he sees the other children, some of them huddled </p> <p>  together, still sleeping, with smiles on 
their faces. Others look </p> <p>  a lot like him, wandering around aimlessly. He is too afraid to </p> <p> speak to them. The energy is gone. They are all still here. 
We </p> <p>  are all still here. Very still.
Where is the grandmaster? Has he </p> <p>  ascended? If he had ascended, why are the children still here? </p> <p>  Why is everything still here? He comes out of the
woods, into </p> <p>  the clearing where they have built their houses. There is no </p> <p> music playing, as there so often was. It is beginning to rain. </p> <p>  Good for the
crops. He eyes the grandmaster's treehouse. He has </p> <p> never been there. Grandmaster always told them that they </p> <p> should not visit his lodging unless it was 
an absolute </p> <p> emergency. And even then, if Daydream was available, they </p> <p> were supposed to tell her and she was to summon him. But if </p><p> there ever was an 
emergency, this was it. Striding towards the </p> <p> abode of the mistaken soothsayer, he tries to project confidence </p> <p> as best as he can, but he is sure it is
not working.
He arrives at </p> <p> the bottom of the rope ladder, and calls up to the grandmaster. </p> <p> "Grandmaster!" He is surprised to hear his own voice; he had </p> <p>not heard
it by itself for so long. It does not sound the way that </p> <p> he remembered it. But there is no response. He yells louder, but </p> <p> still no reply. He looks around
warily, seeing only wayward </p> <p> children still dwindling around the edge of the woods, unsure of </p> <p> how to continue. He drops his shoes and takes a step onto the </p> <p>
ladder. He struggles even to balance on the first rung, but </p> <p> pushes up. Swinging back and forth, he forces himself to reach </p> <p> the top. He places his elbows
on the floorboards, and peers </p> <p> through the open door. There the grandmaster sits. His throat </p> <p> laughing blood, Daydream sleeping forever in his arms.
 James </p> <p>  falls. It's about a six foot drop. Nothing terrible, but air seems </p> <p>  to flit away from him with each breath now. He lays on his </p> <p> back. The oxygen
is coming back to him, a tempestuous sylph </p> <p> seeming sometimes to tempt him with an especially full breath</p> <p> before teasing away again. But as he lays, it 
comes back to him. </p> <p> It gets easier and by the end he breathes easily, his own form of </p> <p> meditation. Some time passes, he is not sure how much, before </p> <p> he
rises to his feet. He is not sure whether he is in shock, but the </p> <p> pain of the fall seems to have displaced the horror of what he </p> <p> had seen.
He goes back to his quarters, an old school bus that he </p> <p> shares with about eight other men as living quarters. The </p> <p> steering wheel was still attached,
but the bus did not drive. Idly, </p> <p> he sits and gives the steering wheel a turn or two. One man lays </p> <p> on his mat, blissful and unconscious, like a stuffed 
animal. He </p> <p> must have made his way back in the technicolor stupor. Habit is </p> <p> a powerful hand to hold. Again, James is too afraid to wake </p> <p> him, too afraid
to speak to him. He does not know these people. </p> <p> He only knows the grandmaster, and he has gone. 
James sits </p> <p> incredulous in the seat of the bus. A riddling strand of accordion </p> <p> rain weeps across the window, leaving behind it a trail of </p> <p>
self-fragments before breaking up into nothing. The silence </p> <p> which at first oppressed him, seemed to conjure up a kind of </p> <p> peace within him now. 
There was no silence before. No matter </p> <p> how early you woke up. Always people singing, yelling, </p> <p> chanting their mantras, or perhaps the grandmaster 
would be </p> <p> giving a sermon. He had a booming voice, one that really got </p> <p> under your skin and frisked your spirit. But now, the noise </p> <p> subsided, James
can think again.
He thinks first about how he </p> <p> has no wallet, no ID, no social security number, no cellphone </p> <p> and how there’s no landline. He then thinks about how 
he's not </p> <p> sure how to get home, or if there still is a home. He hasn't talked </p> <p> to his mother or father in years. They probably would not have </p> <p> missed
him anyway. What is there for him, out there? But then, </p> <p> what is here? He peers out the window. It seems that the </p> <p> children have discovered the untimely 
death of the grandmaster. </p> <p> They are tearing anything and everything apart. They are </p> <p> pulling the crops up, biting them and then spitting them onto </p> <p> the
ground. The shepherd has gone, and the sheep have grown </p> <p> rabid in his absence.
James isn't quite sure what to do. So he </p> <p> just holds the steering wheel of the old school bus, and turns it. </p> <p> Round and round, round and round.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hm... Maybe I wasn't clear. Let me better outline what I'm trying to do"

1. Words should appear when the user hovers over them.

2. The words should never reappear again after the mouse leaves, even if the user hovers over them again.

3. Some words should remain lit and always remain lit, my exceptions.

4. Some words should not be lit, but when they are hovered over, remain lit even when the mouse does not hover over them, my moreExceptions. 

Number 4, is the difficulty I'm having right now.

Comment: @jeepersmcface you should have start with question like this comment =) it's clearer. So I updated my answer in accordance with our clarifications ;)

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try to be more clear in the future! Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Ok so it looks like you've got the basic idea.

1. Setup CSS styling for two classes, one which represents an item waiting to be hovered over and another which represents an item being hovered over... Check
2. Make sure that the hovering class comes after the hover class... Check
3. Make js functions to change class when mouse enters or leaves... Close

Here's what step 3 should look similar to:

```
$('p').not('.hovering').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).AddClass('hovering'); 
});

$('.hovering').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).RemoveClass('hovering');
});
```

Or you could do this all in CSS and get rid of the js and the extra 'hovering' class while you're at it with the following code:

```
.hover {
    opacity: 0;
}
.hover:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

This accomplishes the same effect as before without the complexity.  Also if you want to make the words fade in and out on hover you just need to add some CSS transitions to this CSS code.

Hope this helps.